# Data Chart display

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization

I want to display some values on graphic using a Chart in C#. I am using the following code

```
 graphics.graphic1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 14);
 graphics.graphic1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(4, 0);               
 graphics.graphic1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(12, 4);
 graphics.graphic1.Series[0].Points[0].AxisLabel = "lll";
 graphics.graphic1.Series[0].Points[1].AxisLabel = "bbb";
 graphics.graphic1.Series[0].Points[2].AxisLabel = "ccc";
```

to set some point values and some text on the X axis for each point. The problem is that the text is not shown.

What should I do in order to display the text on X axis beneath each point?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Passing value to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490057/passing-values-to-another-class-c-sharp-wpf/21496487#21496487)
you can find a complete working example of a chart using OxyPlot.WPF. If you have not gone too far with your app (which seems to be in WinForms), consider switching to WPF, it will be worth your while. Specifically, the result in that example is that without doing any special effort you get a chart with automated zoom as well as manual zoom (mouse wheel) on X and on Y.
switching to a DateTime x-Axis is as simple as changing the type of the axis in the XAML from:

```
<oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" Title="Curvature (rad/in)" TitleFont="Arial" TitleFontSize="12" TitleColor="Black"/>
to:
<oxy:DateTimeAxis Position="Bottom" Title="Time" TitleFont="Arial" TitleFontSize="12" TitleColor="Black"/>
```

then when zooming you see your X-Axis automatically changing from Time only at 1 minute resolution to a 10 minute resolution to hourly, and then to date resolution... Magic.
I was really impressed by the results of this (see full example in the link).

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using Windows Form Application, not WPF

Comment: I noticed, and even so thought to propose you to switch...It may be a bit complicated at the beginning but it pays off sooner than you think.